# Primeng captcha issue with angular 6

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using [primeng captcha](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/captcha) with angular 6 and I have an issue.
When I try to directly load the page that has captcha confirmation I have this error:

> ERROR TypeError: window.grecaptcha.render is not a function
>       at Captcha.push../node_modules/primeng/components/captcha/captcha.js.Captcha.init (captcha.js:42)
>       at Captcha.push../node_modules/primeng/components/captcha/captcha.js.Captcha.ngAfterViewInit (captcha.js:32)

I have only initialized the captcha in my index.html:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

But it works if I route to this page from another page.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this, so what I did was to attach the `window.grecaptcha` object to my component, and then `*ngIf` the captcha until `grecaptcha.render` is truthy. Check it.

```
// In your component
ngOnInit(){
    this.recaptcha = (window as any).grecaptcha;
}

// And then in your template
<ng-container *ngIf="recaptcha.render">
    <p-captcha ...></p-captcha>
</ng-container>
```

Doing this, the captcha component won't run until the script has executed and the `render` functions exists on the `grecaptcha` global.

Cheers. Best of luck to whoever finds this issue.

Comment: BTW, I am also using Angular6 + PrimeNG Captcha