# Captcha widget keep disappearing (primeng captcha p-captcha)

Tags: typescript, spring-boot, angular6, primeng

I am using priming-captcha for my application. It is working fine when I am routing the page through some other page. But the captcha doesn't show when I am loading page directly (**sometime it shows grecaptcha.render is not a function in console**)

As specified in primefaces I have added the script (`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js ... tRecaptcha" async defer></script>`) in index.html.

Also, I have added this (`<p-captcha id="captcha" siteKey="sitekey" label="Captcha" (onResponse)="func($event)"></p-captcha>`) in my some-component.html.

I am trying to explicitly render it. But still no luck. Can someone please help me with a sample onLoad function and where to implement. Whether it should be implemented in script of index.html or somewhere else.

index.html

```
<!doctype html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Title</title> <base href="/"> <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit&onLoad=initRecaptcha" async defer></script> </head> <body> <app-root></app-root> </body> </html>
```

password-recovery.component.html

```
<div class="p-col-11"> <p-captcha id="captcha" siteKey="sitekey" (onResponse)="storeRecaptchaResponse($event)" #captcha></p-captcha> </div>
```

password-recovery.component.ts

```
storeRecaptchaResponse(event) { this.recaptchaSubmitted = true; this.recaptchaResponse = event.response; console.log('Captcha Response ' + this.recaptchaResponse); }
```

Comment: Show me you code

Comment: Can you update the code in your question? not in comments.

Comment: And let me know your primeng version? is it 8.1.1

Comment: primeng version - 7.1.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794121/primeng-captcha-issue-with-angular-6

Comment: Already tried. Not working